# Display most used vowel in a string c#

Tags: c#, string, count

I count the vowels and the consonant in a string. Now I want to display the most used vowel and consonant in this string the code that I have for the counting

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        char[] charArray = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        string line = testBox.Text.ToLower();

        char letter;
        int vowels = 0;
        int sug = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            letter = line[i];

            if (charArray.Contains(letter))
                vowels++;
            if (!charArray.Contains(letter))
                sug++;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("number of vowels is" + vowels.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("number of vowels is" + sug.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I think you should consider extracting the vowel/consonant evaluation to some char extension methods. I'd probably also create other extension methods to get an IEnumerable<char> of vowels and consonants from a given IEnumerable<char> too. I suspect your whole solution would be _much_ more clean this way.

Answer (score 4):

Make the vowels and constants lists instead of an int counter then you can manipulate each list at a later stage.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        char[] charArray = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        string line = testBox.Text.ToLower();

        char letter;
        List<char> vowels = new List<char>();
        List<char> sug = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            letter = line[i];

            if (charArray.Contains(letter))
                vowels.Add(letter);
            if (!charArray.Contains(letter))
                sug.Add(letter);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("number of vowels is" + vowels.Count);
        MessageBox.Show("number of vowels is" + sug.Count);

        MessageBox.Show("most used vowel: " + vowels.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(xs => xs.Count()).Select(xs => xs.Key).First());
        MessageBox.Show("most used constant: " + sug.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(xs => xs.Count()).Select(xs => xs.Key).First());
    }
```

Comment: List<char> vowels = 0;
        List<char> sug = 0; is it possible to have a list =0 ?

Comment: How I can display how many times the most used vowel and constant are displayed

Comment: Use .Count() instead of .First().

Comment: MessageBox.Show("most used vowel: " + vowels.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(xs => xs.Count()).Select(xs => xs.Key).Count());
        MessageBox.Show("most used constant: " + sug.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(xs => xs.Count()).Select(xs => xs.Key).Count());

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is one way to do it. It may be a little more advanced due to the heavy use of linq and lambadas. It does work, but I would recommend breaking some of the functionality out into functions.

```
char[] charArray = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
string line = "bbcccaaaeeiiiioouu";

var vowelCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach(var vowel in charArray)
{
    vowelCounts.Add(vowel, line.Count(charInString => vowel == charInString));
}

var consonantCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach(var consonant in line.Where(charInString => !charArray.Contains(charInString)).Distinct())
{
    consonantCounts.Add(consonant, line.Count(charInString => consonant == charInString));
}

KeyValuePair<char, int> mostUsedVowel = vowelCounts.OrderBy(Entry => Entry.Value).FirstOrDefault();
KeyValuePair<char, int> mostUsedConsonant = consonantCounts.OrderBy(Entry => Entry.Value).FirstOrDefault();

string output1 = String.Format("The Vowel '{0}' was used {1} times", mostUsedVowel.Key, mostUsedVowel.Value);
string output2 = String.Format("The Consonant '{0}' was used {1} times", mostUsedConsonant.Key, mostUsedConsonant.Value);

MessageBox.Show(output1);
MessageBox.Show(output2);
```

Comment: You should seriously consider writing the variables in the standard naming notation (camelCase). Your snippet is very hard to read because the formatter is understanding your variables as classes, displaying them in blue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the code so that it would display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As String is an enumerable of characters You can use LINQs GroupBy function to group by characters an then do all kinds of evaluation with the groups:
http://dotnetfiddle.net/dmLkVb

```
var grouped = line.GroupBy(c=> c);

var vowels = grouped.Where(g => charArray.Contains(g.Key));
var mostUsed = vowels.OrderBy(v => v.Count()).Last();

Console.WriteLine("Distinct characters: {0}:", grouped.Count());
Console.WriteLine("Vowels: {0}:", vowels.Count());
Console.WriteLine("Most used vowel: {0} - {1}:", mostUsed.Key, mostUsed.Count());
```

Comment: The output for characters is -1 instead of 8 is 7

Comment: Correct, it's 7 **distinct** characters. I've edited the sample.